# F#'s list is eager or lazy evaluated? Or only "seq" is lazy evaluated in F#

Tags: list, f#, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, seq

Which elements in F# are lazy evaluated, which elements are eager evaluated?
So far as I know, if "seq" is lazy evaluated, does it mean "list" is eager evaluated?
How I prove it? Thanks

Comment: Lists are eagerly evaluated. The answers you got to [your question from February 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35169269/126014) demonstrate that.

Comment: For proof you can look at the type definitions of said types. F# list is defined row 1789: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, list is eager. You can try and watch it in Task Manager for example:

```
#time
let l = List.init 100000000 (fun x -> 0.)
let s = Seq.init 100000000 (fun x -> 0.)
let s2l = s |> Seq.take 10000000 |> Seq.toList
```